# PlayerView onTouch getY() is not constantly giving values

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to implement volume change on swipe, but on top of that i have double tap to seek gesture implemented.
I'm using ExoPlayer 2 and **com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView** and parent is **com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout**

i have `code` like this:

```
float y = motionEvent.getY();
int action = motionEvent.getActionMasked();
switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        iY = y;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float deltaY = motionEvent.getY() - iY;
        float absDeltaY = Math.abs(deltaY);
        if (isFullscreen) {
            Log.e("Delta", "Y: " + deltaY);
            Log.e("AbsDelta", "Y: " + absDeltaY);
            if (absDeltaY > 50) {
                Log.e("action", "Swipe !!!");
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

in `onTouchListener` then comes :

```
gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
return true;
```

gestureDetector is **GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener** which has onDoubleTap and other listeners...

The problem is that deltaY never passes 50 threshold and it stops and requires to re-touch the view. On other hand on views which is not related to PlayerView and its parent, it works like charm.

P.S
This is logcat of multiple touches and swipes:

```
07-23 16:32:08.879 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -0.67178345
07-23 16:32:08.879 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 0.67178345
07-23 16:32:08.896 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -1.6026917
07-23 16:32:08.896 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 1.6026917
07-23 16:32:08.915 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -2.527893
07-23 16:32:08.915 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 2.527893
07-23 16:32:08.929 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -2.8125
07-23 16:32:08.929 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 2.8125
07-23 16:32:10.471 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: 1.5309906
07-23 16:32:10.471 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 1.5309906
07-23 16:32:10.486 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: 3.1208649
07-23 16:32:10.486 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 3.1208649
07-23 16:32:10.503 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: 12.975586
07-23 16:32:10.503 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 12.975586
07-23 16:32:10.520 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: 23.091217
07-23 16:32:10.520 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 23.091217
07-23 16:32:12.178 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -1.0716248
07-23 16:32:12.178 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 1.0716248
07-23 16:32:12.195 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -1.640625
07-23 16:32:12.195 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 1.640625
07-23 16:32:12.211 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -2.7798767
07-23 16:32:12.211 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 2.7798767
07-23 16:32:12.228 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -4.5023193
07-23 16:32:12.228 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 4.5023193
07-23 16:32:12.244 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -6.4189453
07-23 16:32:12.244 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 6.4189453
07-23 16:32:12.261 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -14.851379
07-23 16:32:12.261 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 14.851379
07-23 16:32:12.278 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -21.367462
07-23 16:32:12.278 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 21.367462
07-23 16:32:13.181 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -0.68240356
07-23 16:32:13.182 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 0.68240356
07-23 16:32:13.198 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -1.6026611
07-23 16:32:13.199 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 1.6026611
07-23 16:32:13.215 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -3.2275085
07-23 16:32:13.215 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 3.2275085
07-23 16:32:13.231 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -5.7579346
07-23 16:32:13.232 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 5.7579346
07-23 16:32:13.248 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -13.611542
07-23 16:32:13.248 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 13.611542
07-23 16:32:14.120 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -0.87713623
07-23 16:32:14.120 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 0.87713623
07-23 16:32:14.136 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -1.8153687
07-23 16:32:14.137 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 1.8153687
07-23 16:32:14.152 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -2.7530518
07-23 16:32:14.152 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 2.7530518
07-23 16:32:14.169 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -4.1118164
07-23 16:32:14.170 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 4.1118164
07-23 16:32:14.185 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -5.9500732
07-23 16:32:14.186 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 5.9500732
07-23 16:32:14.204 20932-20932/test.test E/Delta: Y: -16.7305
07-23 16:32:14.204 20932-20932/test.test E/AbsDelta: Y: 16.7305
```